# MSAccess: Proper use of Nz in a query?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am attempting to construct an UPDATE query string (strSQL) in my AccessDB.  One of the attributes in my query can legitimately = NULL.

I've surrounded the attribute with Nz([ID]), as follows - Note:  [ID] is an Integer value:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE Table... " & _
    "WHERE ((Table.Attr1 = " &  nz(forms!form1!subForm1.Form![ID]) & ") AND (Table.Attr2 = 'Test'));"
db.execute strSQL
```

Access complains about an "extra )" in my query expression.  Note:  Current Query works just fine when [ID] <> Null

I also tried surrounding [ID] with Nz([ID],0) - Access no longer complains, but returns no result, as [ID] is never 0 in my table.

Any suggestions for proper use of Nz() in this context?

Thanks!

Here is the actual strSQL result from debug.print - easy enough to see the offending WHERE clause:

```
UPDATE TblMatchedTb SET TblMatchedTb.FLAG_UNMATCHED = 'CLP', TblMatchedTb.UNM_ID = Null, TblMatchedTb.ITEM = Null, TblMatchedTb.COST = 0, TblMatchedTb.PACK = 1, TblMatchedTb.UOM = 'EA', TblMatchedTb.LastUpdated = #3/17/2014 8:14:48 PM#, TblMatchedTb.LastUpdatedby = '22' WHERE ((TblMatchedTb.UNM_ID= ) AND ((TblMatchedTb.ITEM)= '') AND ((TblMatchedTb.COST)= 6.882) AND ((TblMatchedTb.PACK)= 1) AND ((TblMatchedTb.UOM)= 'EA'));
```

Comment: Add a line with `Debug.Print strSQL` just before `db.execute strSQL`.  Run the code, and when it throws that error, copy the `Debug.Print` output from the Immediate window and paste it into your question.

Comment: If that's your real code, what's with the `UPDATE Table...`? (And if it's not your real code - you may find getting help difficult.)

Comment: I tried to simply the strSQL for discussion's sake...  Full strSQL result is posted above...

Comment: Thanks, Mark.  What *should* this piece of the query look like? ... `WHERE ((TblMatchedTb.UNM_ID= )`  Should it be `UNM_ID Is Null` or `UNM_ID=<some number>`?

Comment: Dedicate a variable to hold the value of `forms!form1!subForm1.Form![ID]`.  Start finding out what's wrong with that part.

Comment: The strSQL is based upon the currently selected record on the subform.  [UNM_ID] can be NULL or an INT value depending upon the record selected...  I guess that's my complication.

Comment: Note:  There may be MANY records meeting the criteria - the subform is displaying just the UNIQUES

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `SELECT` query to work out the `WHERE` clause logic.  After you have that working correctly, use the same `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE` query.

I think you're saying you want rows whose `UNM_ID` values equal a text box, `ID`, when the text box is not Null.  But, when the text box is Null, you want rows where `UNM_ID` is Null.

If that's correct, use a variant variable to hold the `ID` value as Smandoli suggested.  Then you can use an `IIf` expression to decide between equal to and is Null.

```sql
Dim strSQL As String
Dim varID As Variant

varID = Forms!form1!subForm1!ID.Value

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM TblMatchedTb AS m" & vbCrLf & _
    "WHERE m.UNM_ID " & _
    IIf(IsNull(varID), "Is Null", "=" & varID) & _
    " AND ..."
Debug.Print strSQL
```

Comment: Yes, perfect!  Thanks once again HansUp.  I was on this path to test for NULL and conditionally construct the strSQL.  IIF is much more efficient.